# Postscript - rangecheck - xyshow - operatortype

Tags: printing, postscript

Currently on around 10% of all prints that we do using PDF's converted to Postscript we get the following error:-

ERROR: rangecheck
OFFENDING COMMAND: xyshow  COMMANDTYPE: operatortype

From reading up this indicates that there is something within the file which is going outside of a numarray or numstring. Looking at the actual prints there is nothing that appears over large, apart from a single body of text but that is printed on every single page - 90% of the prints come out OK so I assume that can't be the cause.

The only two fields which change in size between files are an article description and a customer name. The article description seems to range upwards of 30 characters, i have had a failure at 31 characters and a success at 32. Customer names are always less characters than this.

If it makes any difference there are multiple barcodes also being printed as part of these documents - all barcodes values while different are the same number of characters.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the PostScript Language Reference Manual:

```
xyshow    string  numarray    xyshow  –
          string  numstring   xyshow  –
...
...
If numarray or numstring is exhausted before all the characters of string have been shown, a rangecheck error occurs.
```

This is most likely the source of the problem. However, since you haven't supplied an example file, its impossible to tell for sure.

This would suggest a fault in the conversion from PDF to PostScript, and you haven't said how you are doing that, either, which makes it impossible to offer any advice.